# Google Remarketing tag showing broken image

Tags: html, css

I have added Google Remarketing tag to my website, and at the bottom, after the footer area, a small broken image is shown.

I tried to set height and width to zero but nothing happened, the image is still there. Also tried clearing cookies and opening in incognito window.

[image]

Has anyone faced this problem before?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1042939904;
var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
var google_remarketing_only = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:inline;">
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt=""     src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/1042939904/?    value=0&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Can you post the html and css code?

Comment: Its a basic WordPress website and Google Remarketing Tag